# Which is the best site for video uploading supporting FTP upload and maximum length video?

Tags: upload, video-streaming

I am looking for website where I can upload gigabytes of videos and no time limit.
And the upload can be done via FTP.

Even if it requires payment, it's all right, but I want the FTP feature.

Answer (score 1):

[Bits on the Run](http://www.longtailvideo.com/bits-on-the-run) seems to support FTP, according to their [online documentation](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/bits-on-the-run/15964/upload-large-files-over-ftp). They're the same people who also develop the [JW Player](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players).

Answer (score 1):

[NimbusHD](http://www.nimbushd.com) supports upload by transfer (FTP or HTTP pull), and no time limit on video duration.